# Using setTimeout to pause rest API calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an array of IDs and a fix endpoint that I need to call. So I want to foreach the array of IDs and make a corresponding rest API call for each ID. Since I don't want to "flood" the endpoint, I want to wait a second between each call. Also, I'd like to wait for the response before calling endpoint with a new ID.

Here's what I came up with:

```
// Code goes here
console.clear();

const url = 'some-domain.com/v1/api/users';
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const serviceMock = (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  console.log('Got request for id ' + id);
  setTimeout(() => {

    resolve(`${url}${id} returned ${ Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)}`);
  }, 2000);
});

const main = async() => {

  let index = 0;
  for (let id of ids) {

    index++;
    setTimeout(async() => {

      const data = await serviceMock(id);
      console.log(`Done for user ${id}!`);
      console.log(data);
    }, 1000 * index);
  }
};

main();
```

The `setTimeout` in serviceMock is used to simulate the rest API call, and the `setTimeout` in `main` is used to pause between the calls.

Now, how I would like it to behave is as follows (in console):

```
Got request for id 1
Done for user 1!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users1 returned 77
Got request for id 2
Done for user 2!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users2 returned 75
Got request for id 3
Done for user 3!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users3 returned 26
Got request for id 4
Done for user 4!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users4 returned 44
Got request for id 5
Done for user 5!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users5 returned 79
Got request for id 6
Done for user 6!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users6 returned 52
Got request for id 7
Done for user 7!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users7 returned 34
```

This is what I get:

```
Got request for id 1
Got request for id 2
Got request for id 3
Done for user 1!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users1 returned 77
Got request for id 4
Done for user 2!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users2 returned 75
Got request for id 5
Done for user 3!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users3 returned 26
Got request for id 6
Done for user 4!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users4 returned 44
Got request for id 7
Done for user 5!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users5 returned 79
Done for user 6!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users6 returned 52
Done for user 7!
some-domain.com/v1/api/users7 returned 34
```

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/sNfk8GIfqbhrpql5hQ16?p=preview

what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: You never wait for the `setTimeout` callback. In fact you cannot `await` a callback, you can only wait for a promise - just create one for the delay, exactly like you already demonstrated in `serviceMock`.

Comment: hmm, something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/7n6ysTt0tn9UdlUV7ppp is it still necessary to do this in `setTimeout`: `1000 * index` ?

Comment: Yes, something like that, however a) put the `serviceMock(id)` in its own `await` after the delay, not inside the callback b) make a helper function for the delay promise c) you don't need the multiplication any more

Comment: Oh, so you think a solution like user 'Sunday' suggested below? Something in this manner http://plnkr.co/edit/ruzf09vqMspps6JEjxTo?p=preview

Comment: Yes, exactly what he suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put 'await' in setTimeout.

I suggest you write *wait* function:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
);
```

Now you can easily type:

```
const main = async () => {

  let index = 0;
  for (let id of ids) {
    index++;

    await wait(1000);

    const data = await serviceMock(id);
    console.log(`Done for user ${id}!`);
    console.log(data);
  }

};

main();
```

Comment: an interesting approach, I must say! Here's a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/lbZBh7fRrm2ehFQHzmcO?p=info

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive solution:
create a variable `var i = 0` to hold the current index of your ID array.
Next create a function `x()` that makes your API call. In the success function of your API call, increment `i` i.e the current index of your ID array, then do a check `i == array.length` if true do nothing if false call function `x()` again.

Comment: this is my current solution, yes, but i thought recursion was a bit unnecessary for this kind of work. I didn't increment a variable, but just took first id from the array and so forth, e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/xcS1vkOD4qzWMHMORb5u